# How to Create a Spring+Primefaces+Hibernate (no maven) project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, primefaces

I am new to J2EE. I would like to create a Spring+Primefaces+Hibernate project. 
I googled for it.
But I found all projects examples show in internet contains maven. My questions are

1. Is it possible to create a spring+primefaces+hibernate project in eclipse without **Maven**? If no, what is need of maven?
2. How to add the jar file of primefaces and spring and hibernate in eclipse?
3. Will the spring controller xml file (spring context or dispatcher servlet) be created automatically or manually?I mean **Spring MVC**.
4. Will the hibernate file (mapping file) also be created automatically or manually?
5. If possible, can anyone guide me to tutorial (preferably video) to implement the same?

I am using tomcat 7 and Eclipse - kepler.

Any help is appreciated.

If this is downvoted , do specify the reason also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Although it's not a 'must' to use Maven or any other build tool, you should strongly consider using one.Eclipse Kepler has by default maven support but feel free to use other build tools(Gradle, Ant) or **none**(see 2.).Maven and the other build tools remove the headache of scaffolding, searching for dependencies(external jars like spring-mvc, hibernate, some db drivers), even deploying applications in a server.
2. If you chose not to use a build tool you have to manually get your project dependencies and enter them
   into your project's buildpath(Right Click -> Build Path then enter their location).As you have noticed this step can be really really time consuming...
3. No, you have to manually create the configuration unless you use another project that already has what you need, again this might get easier with a build tool(maven archetypes for example)
4. The same as 3.
5. You won't have a hard time finding resources about these technologies, they are being used practically everywhere, and I think the Spring team has some videos in their YouTube channel.

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: when i googled in internet, all resources that i came across was a maven implementation. But i would like use a non maven resource which havent come across till now. If you know any resources that meets my need, it will be helpfull if u can redirect me to the same.

Comment: It's true that the vast majority of the examples use maven.You can open pom.xml in the root directory(contains maven configuration) of the example you like and for every dependency like this:<dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.27</version>
</dependency>
            ,download the equivalent .jar file, in this example here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.27 . Pay attention also in the rest of the configuration, for example if it's a web app you 'll need to make it a .war file and other minor details

Comment: so if i donot want maven , i have to just download those files in mentioned in pom.xml and add it to my project. Right

Comment: Check the rest of the configuration in pom.xml to know for sure but generally yes just download those dependencies.Again consider using a build tool, it will simplify a lot your work

Answer (score 1):

1:* The fundamental difference between Maven and Ant is that Maven's design regards all projects as having a certain structure and a set of supported task work-flows (e.g., getting resources from source control, compiling the project, unit testing, etc.). While most software projects in effect support these operations and actually do have a well-defined structure, Maven requires that this structure and the operation implementation details be defined in the POM file. Thus, Maven relies on a convention on how to define projects and on the list of work-flows that are generally supported in all projects.
This design constraint resembles the way that an IDE handles a project, and it provides many benefits, such as a succinct project definition, and the possibility of automatic integration of a Maven project with other development tools such as IDEs, build servers, etc.
But one drawback to this approach is that Maven requires a user to first understand what a project is from the Maven point of view, and how Maven works with projects, because what happens when one executes a phase in Maven is not immediately obvious just from examining the Maven project file. In many cases, this required structure is also a significant hurdle in migrating a mature project to Maven, because it is usually hard to adapt from other approaches.
In Ant, projects do not really exist from the tool's technical perspective. Ant works with XML build scripts defined in one or more files. It processes targets from these files and each target executes tasks. Each task performs a technical operation such as running a compiler or copying files around. Targets are executed primarily in the order given by their defined dependency on other targets. Thus, Ant is a tool that chains together targets and executes them based on inter-dependencies and other Boolean conditions.
The benefits provided by Ant are also numerous. It has an XML language optimized for clearer definition of what each task does and on what it depends. Also, all the information about what will be executed by an Ant target can be found in the Ant script.
A developer not familiar with Ant would normally be able to determine what a simple Ant script does just by examining the script. This is not usually true for Maven.
However, even an experienced developer who is new to a project using Ant cannot infer what the higher level structure of an Ant script is and what it does without examining the script in detail. Depending on the script's complexity, this can quickly become a daunting challenge. With Maven, a developer who previously worked with other Maven projects can quickly examine the structure of a never-before-seen Maven project and execute the standard Maven work-flows against it while already knowing what to expect as an outcome.
It is possible to use Ant scripts that are defined and behave in a uniform manner for all projects in a working group or an organization. However, when the number and complexity of projects rises, it is also very easy to stray from the initially desired uniformity. With Maven this is less of a problem because the tool always imposes a certain way of doing thi

2:* You have to download all required jars file for hibernate/spring/primefaces from internet and place them in your project build path or in lib folder.

3:* Spring configuration files need to be created by you so that you can get the concept.

4:* Hibernate mapping files can be created by using reverse Engineering techniques for hibernate from where you can generates hbm files or you can use annotations if you dont want xml.

I suggest you to first create a sample java project in eclipse then download all required jars and place them in lib folder. Then configure hibernate in projects and spring integration.